# How to get the intercept from a linear model with lasso (lars R package)

Tags: r, lasso-regression, lars, intercept

I am having an hard time in getting the model estimated by the R package `lars` for my data.

For example I create a fake dataset x and corresponding values y like this:

```
x = cbind(runif(100),rnorm(100))
colnames(x) = c("a","b")
y = 0.5 + 3 * x[,1,drop = FALSE]
```

Next I train a model that uses lasso regularization using the lars function:

```
m = lars(x,y,type = "lasso", normalize = FALSE, intercept = TRUE)
```

Now I would like to know what is the estimated model (`that I know to be: y = 0.5 + 3 * x[,1] + 0 * x[,2]`)

I am only interested in the coefficients obtained in the last step:

```
cf = predict(m, x, s=1, mode = "fraction", type = "coef")$coef
cf
a b 
3 0
```

These are the coefficients that I expect, but I can't find a way to get the intercept (`0.5`) from `m`.

I have tried to check the code of `predict.lars`, where the fit is done as such:

```
fit = drop(scale(newx, 
           object$meanx, FALSE) %*% t(newbetas)) + object$mu)
```

I can see that the variables are scaled, and that the mean of `y` (object$mu) is used, but I can't find an easy way to obtain the value of the intercept I am looking for. How can I get that?

Comment: Hi, you can replace `x` with `cbind(1,x)` to add a column of ones and use the option `intercept=FALSE`.

Comment: ... but it is not a good idea because lasso could set the intercept at 0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`intercept=T` in `lars` has the effect of centering the x variables and y variable. It doesn't include an explicit intercept term with a coefficient.

That being said, you could do `predict(m,data.frame(a=0,b=0),s=2)$fit` to get the predicted value of y when the covariates are 0 (the definition of a traditional intercept)

Comment: thanks, I was looking for a way to access them from the data structure, but it doesn't seam to be possible..
Another way I have found, is using the fact that you have fit the model (y - ym) = b1*(x1 - x1m) + b2*(x2 - x2m), so that the intercept in terms of your un-centred variables is y = (y -b1*xm1 - b2*xm2) where the m denotes the mean of the variables